# Installing Symantec Endpoint Protection clients via group policy in a mixed environment

Tags: group-policy, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection

we're upgrading to Symantec Endpoint Protection 12 using group policy in a mixed environment from SAV 10.  how can we tell which machines are 32-bit v. 64-bit?  we tried looking at the properties in AD Users and Computers to no avail thinking we'd create separate OUs for the machines.  our dc is running windows 2003, but we have a 2008 machine we can create policies with.  any ideas?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be accomplished by putting a [WMI filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754488%28WS.10%29.aspx) on your deployment GPO objects. The Group Policy engine on the client machines will check this filter to see if the specific GPO applies to them. It does impact performance, but it'll do what you need.

A good filter could be:

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where OSArchitecture='64-bit'
```

It won't catch any XP-64 you may have around, but should catch the 64-bit Vista and Win7 installs. The inverse of this should catch your 32-bit installs:

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where OSArchitecture<>'64-bit'
```

If it isn't explicitly 64-bit, install the 32-bit version. Alternately, you could just put '32-bit' in there if you'd rather go that route.